# Can you run part of an if statement conditionally?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Let's say I have this if statement:

```
if (
  username === firstname &&
  password !== fakePassword &&
  givenname === lastname

) {
  console.log(`Hi ${firstname}`)
}
```

Now I want to make the given name required if it's longer than 3 characters:

```
const givennameRequired = givenname.length > 3;
```

can I alter the if statement in a way that says "If the `givennameRequired` variable is true then worry about this part"

This way the console logs against two params or three depending on the validity of `givennameRequired`. Obviously I'm trying to avoid using an if/else and having two console logs

In a rough "sudo-code" way (I know this isn't valid):

```
if (
  username === firstname &&
  password !== fakePassword &&
  (
    if (givennameRequired) {
      givenname === lastname
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  )
) {
  console.log(`Hi ${firstname}`)
}
```

Basically, if the length is greater than three evaluate `givenname === lastname` otherwise, return true and don't worry about it.

Comment: What does "I want to make it required if [something that can only be true if it already exists]" mean? If you have multiple usecases, then having an outer and an inner `if` is perfectly fine: "trying to avoid an if/else" is not the right way to go about programming: if that's what you need, then that's what you need.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I fixed the `!===`, it was some sudo anyhow. Not sure what you mean with your question, can you clarify?

Comment: `x.length > 3` can only pass if `x` is already a real thing, so "requiring x, if x>3" makes no sense: we _know_ it exists, there's nothing to require: it's right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
if (
  username === firstname &&
  password !== fakePassword &&
  (givenname.length <= 3 || givenname === lastname)

) {
  console.log(`Hi ${firstname}`)
}
```

The `if` condition only bothers to check `givenname === lastname` if `givenname.length > 3`

Comment: This uses an or so it'll run if the length is greater than three but it still needs to check if it's equal. Using an and here could result in false and it won't run even if it should.

Comment: No, the `||` operator does not evaluate its right term if its left term is `true`.

Comment: @cybersam I think OP wants to add check on `givennameRequired` to the end of this `if`, with some other condition.

Comment: That's the problem. If `length > 3` it needs to make sure the two vars equal. If it's less than three, then the comparison is ignored.

Comment: But your `const givennameRequired = givenname.length > 3` statement generates a `false` value for `givennameRequired` if `givenname.length === 3`. What do you *actually* want to do when `givenname.length === 3`?

Comment: @Styx. I was trying to eliminate the need for `givennameRequired`.

Comment: @cybersam `length === 3` was a mistyped, fixed the comment.

Comment: My code performs the `givenname === lastname` test if and only if `givenname.length > 3`. Otherwise, it does not perfrom that test. That is what you want.

Comment: @dcp3450. In future, please do not alter a comment after someone has already responded to it, as it makes it difficult/impossible to follow the comment flow.

Comment: @cybersam Yes, I get that. I thought OP needed to add this check at the end (with some other check), not with the last check. He edited the question now, and you were right.

Comment: @dcp3450 `givenname === lastname` is only evaluated if `givenname.length <= 3` is FALSE. `givenname.length <= 3` is the inverse of `givenname.length > 3`, meaning that `givenname === lastname` only gets evaluated if `givenname.length > 3` is TRUE. Exactly what you want, right?

Comment: @cybersam sorry for the misunderstanding, looks like that does the trick. Been staring at this code for too long and didn't notice the switched comparison that Lennholm pointed out.

Comment: @Lennholm thanks for pointing out hat comparison switch. That's what was tripping me up on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with an if statement

```
if (givenname.length > 3){
    //do something
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to keep in line with your syntax. Something like this should work. For your own sanity I'd consider nesting the if statements so you can provide more accurate feedback to the user.

```
if (username === firstname && password !== fakePassword && (givennamerequired == true && givenname === lastname && givenname.length() > 3))

) {
  console.log(`Hi ${firstname}`)
}
```

Comment: If required is false or the length is less than three the parentheses will return false and not run the log. However, it should run the long since the other two are equal and the givenname should be ignored.